# Git how to commit changes in a specific tracked directory only and do not include other tracked directories/files in this commit

Tags: git, directory, commit

let say you have 2 tracked directories:

- /dir1/... many files and sub-directories being correctly added and tracked
- /dir2/... many files and sub-directories being correctly added and tracked

For some reason you need to ***commit*** tracked changes in **dir2** separately from **dir1**. I could not find simple solution for that task. Perhaps it is something like `git commit find <your file type filter>` or `ls`, but to me it seems over-complicated, isn't there more simple way to do that? I mean to commit all changes in **dir2** including all it's tracked/untracked content and then commit **dir1** changes in a similar manner? You may have hundreds files/directories so you can't provide whole list of them in single query. From what I see in `git commit dir2/ --dry-run` it still wants to include **dir1** in this commit. Any ideas?

Comment: have you heard about this command we call `git add`

Comment: "From what I see in `git commit dir2/ --dry-run` it still wants to include dir1 in this commit." -> That sounds wrong, what do you see in the output that makes you think this is the case?

Comment: Kim have you read it carefully? I do not know if my description can be more precise. Everything is added and tracked already. I need to do separate commits, but can't figure out how to do it by directory specific way...

Comment: Cem, it shows me a list of files located in dir1 as well as dir2 which I want to commit.

Comment: @NIck, just try to find out what is *index* in terms of git, and how it is related to `git add` command. We believe in you.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes

Comment: @Ryan please clarify if you understand, that I already added everything in both directories by `git add .` + .gitignore. Both dirs are tracked and committed to 'initial commit'; now I need to do separate commits for changes in dir1 and dir2; How do you think `git add` is gonna help me?

Comment: @Kim there is `git add --patch`. I tried it in dir2, but it shows changes in files from dir1 anyway...

Comment: ... have you tried NOT to add the files with `git add` that you do NOT want to have as part of your commit?

Comment: @Kim do you suggest resetting an index? I hoped there was simpler solution, git allows you to commit specific files in a way `git commit FILEPATH1 FILEPATH2` even if everything else is tracked and added. What I wanted is a way to do it based on dir basis since I cannot list all files in a specific directory, there is too much of them.

Comment: If you have things in your index/staging area then yes. Git's workflow is generally to add changes to your index until the index looks like what you want your next commit to look like, then you commit it.